# Is there a "PM"/"P" Torx screw or are they always "TM"/"T"?

Tags: laptop-repair, screws

Is there a "PM"/"P" Torx screw or are they always "TM"/"T"?

The reason:

[The Elitebook 8470p manual](https://www.levnapc.cz/ProductsFiles/hp-elitebook-8470p-servisni-prirucka-en.pdf) mentions two types of screws:

> Remove the four Torx **TM**2.5×8.0 screws (1) from **the rear panel of the computer**.

and

> Remove the eight Torx **PM**2.5×8.0 screws (2) that **secure the base enclosure to the computer**.

Based on searching it seemed like PM could be a typo, since P should be for **P**hillips.

---

Although, the notation there is probably bad as well, because I think they mean

> T8, M2.5

---

The 8460w manual has the same screw somewhere and it says that one ought to only need a "Torx T8" screwdriver. http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03015458.pdf

**NOTE: In the 8460w the PM screws are used also for the rear panel, where the 8470p had TM screws. Possibly they're interchangeable then?**

Comment: They could be Torx Plus or Torx Paralobe. If they were the same size & head pattern, they'd just list 12 TM2.5x8.0 screws.

Comment: @spikey_richie So Torx T is "normal Torx" and Torx P is some special one? How do I identify what the P means?

Comment: I can't find a definitive list of Torx codes. It might also refer to "pan head"...

Comment: @spikey_richie The 8460w manual has the same screw, but mentions one needs **only** a Torx T8 screwdriver. The 8470p manual does not mention that one needs a Torx screwdriver.

Comment: @spikey_richie Possibly, the place where they're used could hint what they are? See updated question.

Comment: The P could denote "pan head" screws while the T could denote "thread forming" (self tapping, for mounting into plastic). To me the M is a part of the M2.5 as in it is a Metric screw with 2.5mm diameter thread. Only a comment because I'm not convinced, I've only ever seen torx denoted by the required driver bit, as in T10 M3x8 Pan Head which would be an M3 screw of 8mm thread length with a pan head that needs a torx T10 driver.